# Gradle Function that changes dependency version according to device api level

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp

Good day.
I need to change OkHttp library version if device version is less than 21 because recent versions of OkHttp does not support these devices.
I thought maybe it's possible to have a gradle function to change it?

Comment: setting minsdkversion wont help here ?

Comment: nope, client really wants to support api 19 even though Google recommends at least api 21

Comment: Use OkHttp 3.12.x for this project.

Comment: It worked! Could you answer the question so I can accept your answer and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use OkHttp 3.12.x for this project." – Jesse Wilson #WWJD